# Test quickly changing scenario using selenium web driver in nodejs

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, jestjs

I have a button which triggers a rest call and upon click of that button until the rest call triggers I disable the button.

I am writing a test case using selenium web driver and nodejs

```
button = driver.findElement(By.class("btn"));
await button.click();

console.log(await button.isEnabled()) //outputs true
```

But I can see that the button is being disabled and I am sure Iam selectingthe correct button the findElement statement.

Comment: I'm confused about what you are attempting. Are you saying that you click the button, it gets disabled, and then you want to wait and click it once it's enabled again?

Comment: @JeffC, I am trying to test the scenario where the button is disabled for a very short amount of time after it is clicked.

Comment: So what is the test? That the button is disabled, is disabled and then reenabled or ?

Comment: Yes the test sis to check if the button is disabled and then re enabled.

Comment: Post the HTML of the button.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `.isEnabled()` says:

> Is the element currently enabled or not? This will generally return true for everything but disabled input elements.

So what you are seeing is expected behaviour.

To test your scenario, you will need the following approach:

1. click your button
2. click the same button again
3. the second click you are expecting to fail, so you will have to wrap it in whatever is the node.js equivalent of `try..catch` (sorry, I'm a Java guy)
4. inside of the catch, set a variable to `true`
5. afterwards test the variable has been set

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you have described is to click a button, verify it becomes disabled, and then verify it becomes enabled. There are probably a few ways to do this. I'm looking at [the documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html) and here is one way:

```
button = driver.findElement(By.class("btn"));
button.click();
driver.wait(until.elementIsDisabled(button));
driver.wait(until.elementIsEnabled(button));
```

If the button never becomes disabled, an exception will be thrown. If the button never becomes reenabled, an exception will be thrown. So, the fail condition is either one throwing an exception. The pass condition is no exceptions.

NOTE: disabled and enabled, in Selenium terms, is generally referring to an `INPUT` tag. If your button is not an `INPUT` tag, then this won't work. You will need to detect some CSS style being applied/removed to determine disabled/enabled.